# How to I do time math and convert to a string for comparison? Progress to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am a Progress programmer and I need to convert the following Progress code and do time math in SQL Server 2008. What is the best way and how does the time math work? Any help is so appreciated. I'm here to learn.

Progress code -

```
endtime = STRING(TIME,"HH:MM:SS")
starttime = STRING(TIME - 1200,"HH:MM:SS")
```

T-SQL code?

```
CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE()) AS hhmmss
```

Comment: If you can explain in words what the 2 progress code line does, I'll bet almost anyone with some t-sql experience will be able to answer the question.

Comment: If TIME is 23:00 then endtime = "23:00"

Comment: starttime = 23:00 - 12:00 = 11:00 = "11:00"

Comment: correction endtime = "23:00:00" and starttime = "11:00:00"

Comment: So end time is 12 hours *before* start time? that doesn't sound right...

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming you want the final value to be of type "string"):

```
SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR( 8 ), CONVERT( TIME, GETDATE()))
SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR( 8 ), DATEADD( hour, -12, CONVERT( TIME, GETDATE())))
```

Explanation:

**CONVERT()** - explicitly converts between data types ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187928.aspx))
**DATEADD()** - adds / substracts number intervals to a date/time value ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx))